# Error Progress Bar

Tags: c#, progressbar

Estoy intentando porner un Progress Bar dentro de mi Proyecto, pero me salta este error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid:
Control 'Progressing_Files' acces from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

De manera general, estoy accediendo a 2 carpetas, leer su contenido, separar por listas y mandarlas
a su propio metodo de insercion, en esto no hay ningun problema.

```
    private void extraccion()
    {
        if (Progressing_Files.InvokeRequired)
         {
             Progressing_Files.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
             {
                 Progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
                 Progressing_Files.Maximum = carpetas.Length + archivos_carpeta1.Length + archivos_carpeta2.Length;
             }));
         }
         else
         {
             Progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
             Progressing_Files.Maximum = carpetas.Length + archivos_carpeta1.Length + archivos_carpeta2.Length;
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < carpetas.Length; i++)
             {
                if (new DirectoryInfo(carpetas[i]).Name == "carpeta1")
                        {
                            //PROCESOS SIN NINGUN PROBLEMA
                        }
                        else if (new DirectoryInfo(carpetas[i]).Name == "carpeta2")
                        {
                            //PROCESOS SIN NINGUN PROBLEMA
                        }


                     if (Progressing_Files.InvokeRequired)
                     {
                         Progressing_Files.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                         {
                             Progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
                             Progressing_Files.Maximum =  carpetas.Length + archivos_carpeta1.Length + archivos_carpeta2.Length;
                         }));
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
                         Progressing_Files.Maximum = carpetas.Length + archivos_carpeta1.Length + archivos_carpeta2.Length;
                     }
                     Progressing_Files.Value++;
          }
          //LISTA CON ARCHIVOS
          carpeta1(lista1, Progressing_Files)
          carpeta2(lista2, Progressing_Files)
    }

private void carpeta1(List<string> lista_1, ProgressBar bar)
        {
            foreach (var item in lista_1)
            {
                //PROCESOS SIN PROBLEMA




                bar.Value++;
            }
        }


private void carpeta2(List<string> lista_2, ProgressBar bar)
        {
            foreach (var item in lista_2)
            {
                //PROCESOS SIN PROBLEMA




                bar.Value++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como dice el error:

> Control `Progressing_Files` acces from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
>
> Se esta intentando acceder a `Progressing_Files` desde un hilo que no sea el hilo en el que se creó.

En estos momentos estoy desde el móvil no puedo hacer una compilación de lo que muestras, pero posiblemente tu error sea porque tienes esto: `Progressing_Files.Value++;` y esto: `bar.Value++;` fuera del `InvokeRequired` y esto también esta modificando el objeto y como esta fuera lanza la excepción.

Aunque veo que estas usando el `InvokeRequired` para controlarlo, puedes hacer algo como esto, para evitar duplicar tanto el mismo código:

Creas una función como esta:

```
private void ModificarUI(Action accion)
{
      if (InvokeRequired)
          Invoke(accion);
      else
          accion();
}
```

Y luego en tu código lo usas así:

```
 ModificarUI(() =>
 {
     Progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
     Progressing_Files.Maximum = carpetas.Length + archivos_carpeta1.Length + archivos_carpeta2.Length;
     Progressing_Files.Value++;
 });
```

Y puedes agregar dentro de ella, otras cosas que modifiquen otros controles y no solo un `ProgressBar`. Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: @Madre Ese es un problema independiente al que reportaste originalmente, la lentitud que mencionas no esta relacionada con el código que he colocado. Debes usar el `Debugger` (Depurar tu códgido) con el VS, para ver lo que esta causando que tus listas estén vacías. Depura paso a paso la ejecución del código.

Comment: Disculpa ya revise mis listas, no hay problema en eso...pero al llegar al primer metodo, sin problema hace la primera insercion, despies de que llega al final, realiza  esto 'bar.Value++;' y regresa al metodo de extraccion, y me manda la misma excepcion del problema principal, cuando con cada archivo insertado el progress deberia de avanzar .

Comment: @Madre La `lista1` y `lista2` no se supone que deben llenarse en el primer ciclo de las carpetas?, porque tienes la invocación de cada función fuera del ciclo?

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error esta indicando que no puedes acceder a controles de usuario desde un `thread` diferente al cual fue creado, o sea el hilo de la `app winform`

El tema es que `carpeta1()` y `carpeta2()` estan accediando al `progressbar` que le pasas por parametro y estos tambien estan dentro del `thread` debes alli tambien usar el `Invoke()`

[Cómo: Realizar llamadas seguras para subprocesos a controles de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)

Entiendo algo de eso quisiste hacer cuando haces uso del `InvokeRequired` pero se supone que vuelvas a invocas `extraccion()` con el valor que quieras asignar al progress

Analiza el ejemplo como lo implementa

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SetText));
    thread2.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private void WriteTextSafe(string text)
{
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new SafeCallDelegate(WriteTextSafe);
        textBox1.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = text;
    }
}

private void SetText()
{
    WriteTextSafe("This text was set safely.");
}
```

Vuelves a invocar a `SafeCallDelegate` pero ahora como `SafeCallDelegate` usando el `Invoke()`

Aqui

[Thread-Safe Calls Using Windows Form Controls in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/thread-safe-calls-using-windows-form-controls-in-C-Sharp/)

se separa el `SetText()`

```
private void SetText(string text)
{
    this .myTextBox.Text=text;
}

private void ThreadProcSafe()
{
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
     string text = "Written by the background thread.";
    if (this.myTextBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text + " (Invoke)" });
   }
    else
    {
        this.myTextBox.Text = text + " (No Invoke)";
    }
}
```

pasando el valor que quieras asignar en el `Invoke()`

Si sabes que `extraccion()` siempre se va a usar dentro de un `thread` no necesitas preguntar por el `InvokeRequired` ya que siempre ingresara por el true, realiza la llamada directa

Lo que recomendaria sino quieres complicarte es que uses el componente `BackgroundWorker` este tiene un evento `ProgressChanged` que puedes usar para actualizar el `ProgressBar`